# Unable to get mongodb _id value in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I tried a lot of tricks to get the value of mongodb _id, but all of them result in error. I tried these:

```
$new_id = new MongoId();
print_r($new_id['_id']); // -> Internal Server Error
echo $new_id['_id']->{'$id'}; // -> Internal Server Error
print_r($new_id); // no error, but useless
```

So, I wonder how to do it right

Comment: Check your server error logs

Comment: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoId as array ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
$mongoId = new \MongoId();
$strId = $mongoId->__toString();

print_r($strId); die;
```

> `MongoId::__toString` — Returns a hexidecimal representation of this
>   id
>
> `public string MongoId::__toString ( void )`

http://php.net/manual/en/mongoid.tostring.php

Please check your server error logs otherwise.

Comment: I did ctrl-c + ctrl-v of your code and still got this error: "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type MongoId as array ..." .

Comment: You were right, Sorry mate. I've corrected my answer. Tested with both, Windows and Linux. Works fine.